# How to say : "Today I worked my chest."?

Tags: vocabulary

Exercise is 锻炼。

我锻炼了我的胸。

Is there a better way to express this ?

Comment: "Today I worked my chest." = 今天我鍛煉了胸肌

Comment: Oops, didn't see your comment until after I posted.

Comment: No worry, I just copied from Google Translate

Comment: In daily conversation we just say 炼胸. 我今天炼了胸, or 我今天炼的胸.

Answer (score 3):

我鍛煉了胸肌。 I exercised my chest muscles.

肌 muscle(s)

我的 is kind of redundant here, since you cannot exercise someone else's chest muscles.

Comment: "我的 is kind of redundant here, since you cannot exercise someone else's chest muscles" Strange that in English you just can't say, "Today I work / exercise chest"?

Comment: Grammar in English works differently. The noun here needs an article (or something that works like an article). Hence, the chest, or my chest. Same thing in "I brush my teeth" In Chinese, it's 我刷牙 rather than *我刷我的牙。

Comment: @WayneCheah a perfect example of how chinese is context based aka topic/comment structure while english isn't.  There are so many things in english that cannot be left off, even though they are obvious in context.  Probably the only time this kind of info can be actually left off in english consistently, is the "you" in commands--and that sure is a specific instance isn't it :)

Answer (score 1):

Today in the body-building studio I was working out my chest muscles.
今天我在健身房锻炼胸肌。

Rocky Horror Picture Show: "In just seven days I can make you a man!"